# ASP Classic 2 arrays with duplicates, 2 new arrays with no duplicates and summed up

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

I have 2 arrays, one with categories and one with price. The 2 arrays are *connected* so that the index matches up on them. I want to get 2 new arrays out of this with no duplicates on the category but with the matching Prices summed up.

**Array1** *Category()*

1. Öppen
2. Läsk/vatten
3. Bartillbehör
4. Öl
5. Vin
6. Vin
7. Cider
8. Cider
9. Cider
10. Cider
11. Likör
12. Likör
13. Sprit
14. Förbrukningsmatrial

**Array2** *SumSamFattArray()*

1. 600,075
2. 3157,38
3. 0
4. 7153
5. 104
6. 64
7. 350
8. 200
9. 0
10. 0
11. 0
12. 0
13. 2643,736
14. 0

This is the Result I want:

**NewFirst Array ()**

1. Öppen
2. Läsk/vatten
3. Bartillbehör
4. Öl
5. Vin      (Vin combined)
6. Cider    (Cider Combined)
7. Likör     (likör combined)
8. Sprit
9. Förbrukningsmatrial

**NewSekond Array ()**

1. 600,075
2. 3157,38
3. 0
4. 7153
5. 168       (The vin combined)
6. 550         (Cider combined)
7. 0          (Likör combined)
8. 2643,736
9. 0

I have been struggling for 2 days with this. Feels like I have tried everything.

How can I combine the two arrays?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Include your code in your post.

Comment: Why are you using two single-dimensional arrays when you could use one multi-dimensional array?

Comment: @Martha: Probably depends on how he gets the data supplied.

Answer (score 0):

If your original array is ordered by category like in your example, then it's pretty simple: loop through the prices, totaling them as you go, moving to the next row every time the category changes. (Note that for simplicity, I'm using 2 two-dimensional arrays rather than 4 single-dimensional arrays.)

```vbs
dim PriceList(1,20) '- actually, I imagine these probably come from a database, in which 
           '- case you'd probably use GetRows rather than explicitly dimming as an array
dim Totals(1,20)
dim n, i
n = 0
Totals(0,0) = ""
For i = 0 to Ubound(Pricelist,2)
    If Pricelist(0,i) & "" <> "" Then
        If Pricelist(0,i) <> Totals(0,n) Then '- next category
            n = n + 1
            Totals(0,n) = Pricelist(0,i) '- write up category
            Totals(1,n) = 0 '-initialize total
        End If
        Totals(1,n) = Totals(1,n) + Pricelist(1,i)
    End If
Next
```

If your original price list is *not* ordered by category, then instead of simply incrementing the row each time the category changes, you'll need to loop through the totals array to find the appropriate row if it exists, or add it if it doesn't.

```vbs
dim PriceList(1,20)
dim Totals(1,20)
dim n, i
dim j, maxN
n = 0 : maxN = 0
Totals(0,0) = ""
For i = 0 to Ubound(Pricelist,2)
    If Pricelist(0,i) & "" <> "" Then
        If Pricelist(0,i) <> Totals(0,n) Then '- not the same category as previous row
            n = 0
            For j = 0 to maxN
                If Pricelist(0,i) = Totals(0,j) Then '- found the category
                    n = j
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If n = 0 then '- didn't find the category, so add it to the end of the list
                maxN = maxN + 1
                n = maxN
                Totals(0,n) = Pricelist(0,i)
                Totals(1,n) = 0
            End If
        End If
        Totals(1,n) = Totals(1,n) + Pricelist(1,i)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim NyBeskArray()`
Dim NySummaArray()
    X=0
    Z=0
    Y=0
    For Each item In SamFattBesk
        Rubrik = SamFattBesk(X)
        Tal = SumSamFattArray(X)
        Tal =Ccur(Tal)
        IF NOT RubrikOld = Rubrik THEN
             ReDim preserve NyBeskArray(Z)
             NyBeskArray(Z) = Rubrik
             ReDim preserve NySummakArray(Z)
             NySummakArray(Z) = Tal
            Z = Z +1
        ELSE
            Y=X-1
            SummaTal = Tal + TalOld
            SummaTal = CCur(SummaTal)
             ReDim preserve NySummakArray(Y)
            NySummakArray(Y) = SummaTal
        END IF
 X=X+1
    RubrikOld = Rubrik
    TalOld = Tal
    Next
    %>
```

Comment: After a while i figure out how this page works.

this is how i solved it.. Maybe not the best way. nut it works. Thanks for helping